# window.showModalDialog Page Load not being executed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-1.1

I am actually loading a page as a modal dialog box as window.showModalDialog("url.aspx"). The first time the modal dialog is poped up the page load event gets called. When i close it and call the same again, the Control does not come to the PageLoad. Instead the page pops up with the previous values in all its controls.

I actually want the PageLoad to be triggered everytime the modal dialog pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok....you do know showModalDialog is an proprietary IE only feature?
As long as you are aware of this then I think you may need to add a unique querystring value to the url that you are using to avoid ie showing the cached version. So generate a random number and append it to the url e.g url.aspx?rnd=12237827348273. This should bust the cache and make a fresh request

Comment: If you have control of the modal page (url.aspx) then why not turn caching off at the page instead of this not-so-elegant hack. Use @OutputCache directive <%@ OutputCache Duration="0" Location="None" VaryByParam="none" %>, or call Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

Answer (score 1):

Apply following directive in the `InPage` of the form:

```
<%@ OutputCache Location="None" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 3 supports https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog